# Regex to change prices in InDesign

Tags: regex, adobe-indesign, digits

I'm working on the new pricelist of my company and I need to change all the prices with an increase of 4%.
I'm using a script for InDesign (Number Adjuster) that works with RegEx.
In the text there are number in two forms:
1.200
430
I successfully changed the first one using (\d.\d{3}), multiplying it for 1.04.
The problem is if a change the 3 digits one with (\d{3}) it changes also the previous ones, but only the part after the dot.
I'd need a regex that matches the 3 digits ones but not the *.*** ones, or alternatevely one that matches both of them, so the script can recalculate all the prices at once.
Also, the articles number are like this: 45.62.54 and I need to change some prices that are two digits, so I need to exclude this kind of string or any two digit number with a dot before or after!
I'm not a programmer so I'm struggling to understand the regex system.

Comment: I'm not a programmer so I'm struggling to understand the regex system. -- I wouldnt worry about that, most programmers struggle to understand the Regex system too lol

Answer (score 0):

This regex :

```
\b\d*\.?\d+\b

// \b\d*\.?\d+\b
// 
// Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
// Match a single digit 0..9 «\d*»
//    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
// Match the character “.” literally «\.?»
//    Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
// Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
//    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
```

Matches an integer or a floating point number with optional integer part.

Also for your first solution :

```
(?<!\.)\d{3}

// (?<!\.)\d{3}
// 
// Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind) «(?<!\.)»
//    Match the character “.” literally «\.»
// Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{3}»
//    Exactly 3 times «{3}»
```

This matches 3 digits who are not preceded by `.` .

This regex :

```
\b\d*(?:\.\d+)?\b\s+
```

Should match only the number. It expects that the numbers are separated by at least one space thus excludes the article numbers 53.44.55 since it's not a valid number. If you have other constraints let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot FD, I added another problem at the end, if you can help me thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, I've succeded in trasforming the "1.200" and "456" prices using (\d.\d{3}) x104, (\d{3}.\d{3}) :100, (?<!\.)\d{3} x104, (\d{2}.\d{3}):100. The problem is if I use (?<!\.)\d{2} x104 it multiplies the first two digits of the article numbers. How can I make so that it ignores the numbers with a dot both before and after them?

Comment: @Gardus Regexes are better at matching things than ignoring things. So  it's better if you match only what you need to match than match everything and then try to ignore something. This is how you ignore numbers with . before and after : (?<!\.)\d{2}(?!\.) But I don't see how this can help you. It will also select numbers which are parts of biggers numbers...

Comment: You're right! As the parts that costs less than 99 € are very few I think I'll fix them manually. You've been of enormous help!! If you ever need a sport exhaust for your car you'll get a very big discount.

Comment: @Gardus :D Thanks for the offer :). Just accept the answer if it helped you and that's enough! :)